# Get uniq values from an array of object created using lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am new to the react, Here I am trying to get the unique elements from the newly created array of object.

```js
const data = _.uniq(
  orderData?.Sessions.map(session => ({
    label: `${session.Activity.Name}`,
    value: `${session.Activity.Name}`
  }))
);
```

I have tried this but, still, it returns me the array of the object which has the unique elements using any of the two keys.

an object should not be duplicated.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `_.uniqBy()`,  refer [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy)

```
const data = _.uniqBy(
  orderData ? .Sessions.map(session => ({
    label: `${session.Activity.Name}`,
    value: `${session.Activity.Name}`
  })), 'label' or 'value'
);
```

It should be either by label or by value

**Example**

```js
document.querySelector("body").onload = function() {
  // By 'label'
  console.log("By label");
  console.log(
    _.uniqBy(
      [
        {'label' : 'name', 'value' : 'Test Name 1'},
        {'label' : 'name', 'value' : 'Test Name 2'},
        {'label' : 'company', 'value' : 'Test Company 1'}
      ], 'label'
    )
  )
  // By 'vlaue'
  console.log("By value");
  console.log(
    _.uniqBy(
      [
        {'label' : 'name', 'value' : 'SO User'},
        {'label' : 'name', 'value' : 'SO User'},
        {'label' : 'company', 'value' : 'Test Company 1'}
      ], 'value'
    )
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `_.uniqBy(data, 'id');//id that is key you have to remove duplicate value from array`

Your Scenario will be used like this

if removed by a **label** then

```
const data = _.uniqBy(
  orderData ? .Sessions.map(session => ({
    label: `${session.Activity.Name}`,
    value: `${session.Activity.Name}`
  })),'label'
);
```

if removed by a **value** then

```
const data = _.uniqBy(
  orderData ? .Sessions.map(session => ({
    label: `${session.Activity.Name}`,
    value: `${session.Activity.Name}`
  })),'value'
);
```

If you get more details then [Link](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy)